# Where can I find tomesh.c?

Tags: graphics

It is used to compare the results in many papers and cited as "Akeley, K., P. Haeberli, and D. Burns, tomesh.c, a C-program on the SGI Developer's Toolbox CD, 1990". But where can I find the source code now?

Thanks,

Comment: I find any realisation.
Check this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643068/where-can-i-find-tomesh-c-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can download an ISO's of the CD's from http://freeware.sgi.com/faq.html#Q3.3

Comment: I can't connect to the downloading server. Is there any mirror anywhere else?