# Where can I find tomesh.c for windows?

Tags: graphics, 3d, sgi

It is used as a reference in many papers:

> K. Akeley, P. Haeberli, and D. Burns. tomesh.c : C Program on SGI
>   Developer's Toolbox CD, 1990.

On official SGI's site, I find only UNIX distributive.

But where can I find source code and short description of the desirable for Windows OS?

---

I find another linear speed cache optimisation algorithm realisation:
http://files.rsdn.ru/38429/ls_vcache_opt.zip
And how to use explanation (but on russial language) with code samle on C++: http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/src/3076506.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464159/where-can-i-find-tomesh-c

Comment: Thanks, but downloading server was unavailable. And I was checked this references before ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/geometry/tomesh.c) to the source. It's straight "C", so it should compile on Windows simply.